# Can we restore database if it was deleted

Tags: database, database-restore

I know i am asking very impractical question but just to know if there is any probability of getting any answer of my question. 
I know importance of back up, but i don't have the backup in anyhow condition.Accidently the database deleted by me. can we recover it ?
Is there any query or steps to restore database ?

Comment: How many databases did you delete to use all those tags?

Comment: Did you really delete your MySQL **and** SQL Server **and** Oracle **and** Informix database at the same time?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `rm / -rf` ;)

Comment: If you have a backup why not?

Comment: guys, i tag all the database because i want to know is there any database which restore without having backup of that database

Comment: @user3736652 restore implies a source. if you don't call it backup it's fine but you do must have a source to restore from...

Comment: @Paolo thanks for the answer. i already mention my point in my thread but just want to know more i post this

Comment: Each DBMS stores its data in a different way, so tagging your question with the *correct* DBMS is important. I retagged this with `database` instead of listing arbitrary DBMS without knowing the real one

Answer (score 1):

On unix, as long as there are processes that run the database, the files still exist. If you deleted the links from the fs to the physical files on disk. The processes have such a link to. As long as they exist, you could try to copy the files using the file descriptors. The results is similar to the restoration of a fuzzy backup but still, that is better than nothing.

See [How Frits did this for redo](http://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2007/05/17/recovery-of-deleted-files-on-linux/)

Better is to think about a backup before you plan a disaster.